# generate non-repeating sequential color plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My goal is to create a barplot visualized with sequential colors.
The only problem I face right now is that the color distribution repeats after a few bars (see pic).

I want the color-distribution to span the whole x-range.

Any ideas how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty easy if you're using matplotlib & seaborn:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn  as sns
x =  range(10)
y =  range(10)
plt.bar(x,y,color= sns.color_palette("BuGn_r", len(x)))
plt.show()
```

just pass the length of the x-array as the 2nd parameter of [color_palette()](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/color_palettes.html)

[image]